# Dynamic Zod Schema

Tags: react-hook-form, zod

I'm trying to add dynamic key to a `formSchema` using `zod`. What I have so far is -

```
const FormSchema = z.object({
    quantity: z.number()
      .positive()
      .min(1)
      .max(20),
    price: z.number()
      .positive()

  });
```

When the component renders, I'll have props like this -

```
const optionProps = [
{
    "name": "select one",
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "lettus"
        },
        {
            "name": "cucumber"
        }
    ],
    "optionFor": "salad",
    "required": true
},
{
    "name": "select one",
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "can of coke"
        },
        {
            "name": "pepsi"
        }
    ],
    "optionFor": "extra",
    "required": true
}
]
```

I want to map `optionProps` and append each `record` to my existing `FormSchema`. So my `formSchema` will become this -

```
const FormSchema = z.object({
    quantity: z.number()
      .positive()
      .min(1)
      .max(20),
    price: z.number()
      .positive(),
salad: z.string(),
extra: z.string()

// or any other valid zod rule. 

  });
```

I'm new to `zod`, Please if anyone can help me, would be great. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can't append to a ```z.object``` like that. There is a ```merge``` method in Zod, which lets you join two Zod schemas to make a new one. Also I dont totally understand what you're trying to do, it would be easier to help with Zod if we knew what the data you want to validate is, and what rules you want to apply on it.

Comment: Hi let me help you understand my problem here. 

I have a product - `spicy chicken pizza`. It comes with few options to choose from. one option is required and another one is optional. example - 

Choose size * 
10" - £7.99
12" - £10.99

once use choose from this list, they will option to choose toppings - 
Extra toppings (optional) 
onion - £0.50
mushroom - £0.50 

You got the idea. Now based on user selection, once they click add to order btn, we will submit the form. But before we will validate. Now some item has 3-4 options, may be 3 required & 1 optional.

Comment: Is what you're saying that you need to generate a validation schema based on the type of pizza?

Comment: Yes. the menu is coming from the DB. We do not know what each menu item's option would look like. For example - a pizza may come with different sizes, toppings or extra. Even the restaurant manager might add more options. 

When you click "margarita pizza" a modal will popup (a recent component), render all options belongs to "margarita pizza" (if there is none, just show add to cart btn). Depending on if option is required or not, we do validation using Zod.

Answer (score 1):

If the data validation logic is coming from a DB, you could generate the validation schema on the fly. You could make a function which takes the data for a pizza and return a validation schema.

I've provided an example on how I would approach this problem. I am assuming all of the salad and extra details for all the pizzas are available on the current page.

```
const generateValidationSchema = (saladMinAmnt = 0, extraMinAmnt = 0) => {
  return z.object({
    quantity: z.number().positive().min(1).max(20),
    price: z.number().positive(),
    salad: z.string().array().min(saladMinAmnt),
    extra: z.string().array().min(extraMinAmnt),
  });
};

const validationSchema = generateValidationSchema(0, 2);
const data = {
  quantity: 10,
  price: 200,
  salad: [],
  extra: ["onion", "mushroom"],
};

const validatedData = validationSchema.safeParse(data);
console.log(validatedData);
```